# Django Queryset not working after tranformation to Abstract class child

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

For more than a year, I construct many of my query using a Django Model where I have simple relation between none abstract model objects and everything was working perfectly :

```
class Taxon(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey("self", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')
    rank = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=False, default="NA")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=False, default="NA")

class Sequence(models.Model):
    taxon = models.ForeignKey(Taxon, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amplicon = models.CharField(max_length=1000, unique=False)
    sequence = models.CharField(max_length=1000, unique=False)
    score = models.FloatField()
```

Exemple of queryset using my Model :

```
taxon.sequence_set.filter(stuff_filtering)
```

But recently I had to apply some modifications on my database and my Sequence objects are now derivated from an Abstract class called Observation, becoming this

```
class Observation(models.Model):
    taxon = models.ForeignKey(Taxon, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Sequence(Observation):
    amplicon = models.CharField(max_length=1000, unique=False)
    sequence = models.CharField(max_length=1000, unique=False)
    score = models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str((self.amplicon, self.sequence, self.score, self.taxon))
```

I didn't changed anything in my queryset because django documentation about abstract class (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/) say you can still use your chlid_set in a query. However i'm facing this error and I couldn't understand why.

```
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'sequence_set'
```

Knowing that in case of Abstract base classes, a table should be created in db for each child with parent attribute... So i have Sequence object with linked Taxon object

Comment: The sequence_set will probably still work, you just need to do it on the Object not the QuerySet. Try doing `your_var.first().sequence_set` .. Might be a good idea to print out that QuerySet var, see if it's returning multiple objects and if so why

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the solution to this problem if to retrieve the Taxon object with a get and not a filter (event if only one object is returned).

```
taxon = Taxon.objects.filter(...)
```

returning just one value became

```
taxon = Taxon.objects.get(...)
```

It's seems a pretty mysterious for me, as  I still don't understand why it has worked perfectly with my previous model